# How to get number of weeks by month in year?

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar, week-number

I want a function that will return an array of week numbers for current month in current year.

For example if the current month is August, 2015 it will return [32, 33, 34, 35, 36]. If month is February, 2015 it will return [6, 7, 8, 9].

Is there a way how can I get this?

In apple docs [NSCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSCalendarUnit) class has an option to get the number of current week in year but It's not what I need.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Ideally you want to show some kind of attempt instead of simply asking for someone to do the work for you.

Comment: http://www.proesite.com/timex/wkcalc.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned `NSCalendar` has a method `rangeOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:`.
The proper calendar units are `CalendarUnitWeekOfYear` and `CalendarUnitMonth`

The result might be different for the locale and first weekday of the week settings.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let weekRange = calendar.rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, inUnit: .CalendarUnitMonth, forDate: NSDate())
let weekArray = Array(weekRange.location..<weekRange.location + weekRange.length)
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let weekRange = calendar.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .month, for: Date())
```

Comment: How to use it in swift 3?. I need to calculate number of weeks in a month.

Answer (score 1):

NSCalendar doesn't give any api directly to get the number of weeks in a month. You have to work around with NSDateComponents and NSDate too.

I can give you the hints but as Steve suggested, you need to try by yourself first.

Try getting a range, look into NSCalendar's method- rangeOfUnit:inUnit:
Think, how you can use this method to get your desired output.

Comment: `rangeOfUnit:inUnit:forDate` is not a workaround, it's the recommended way to do that kind of date math

Comment: sorry, bad english. Let me rephrase my response. Thanks!